# How can we prove that triangle QAB is an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

two equal circles with centre E and F intersect at P and Q. If APB is a straight line, then show that triangle QAB is an equilateral triangle?[image]

Comment: The statement is false in general. Start from two equal circles intersecting at two points $P,Q$. if $AQ$ and $BQ$ are diameters of the two circles, then $APB$ is always colinear.

Comment: Yes it is already mentioned that APB is collinear i.e. straight line in the question. I have already done experimental verification, the statement is absolutely true.

Comment: When the two circle barely touches, $\triangle QAB$ is a close to degenerate isosceles triangle  with $APB$ collinear. The condition $APB$ is collinear is not enough to deduce $\triangle QAB$ is equilateral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The statement should be: "The triangle is isosceles if APB is a straight line.", which can be shown as follow.

Let $r$ be the radius of the two identical circles. Then, with the sine rule

$$AQ= 2r\sin \angle APQ = 2r\sin (180-\angle BPQ) =2r \sin  \angle BPQ=BQ$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a radius of circles.

Thus, $$AQ=AB=2R.$$
Also, $$\measuredangle APQ=\measuredangle BPQ=90^{\circ},$$ which says that always $P\in AB$ and $\measuredangle AQB$ can get any value in $(0^{\circ},180^{\circ}).$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but since the angle of AQB is 90 degrees, it is not an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @schmidt73 I did not say that $\measuredangle AQB=90^{\circ}.$ See please better my post.